# php An active access token must be used to query

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook SDK to get facebook friends list. If I Invoke API with Javascript FB.init(); it works perfectly fine..

but if I use it directly like

```
facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $appid,
'secret' => $secret
));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
try{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    print_r($user_profile);
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

(User is logged in with facebook in the same browser)
It always gives me an error : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Please help me how to use it without FB.init() or redirect anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $appid,
'secret' => $secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
if($fbuser){
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
   $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
   try{
       $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
       print_r($user_profile);
   } catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
}else{
  // User not logged in generate the login button or link here
}
```

Make sure in the above script when user login ffor the first time it reloads the page in other words you need to provide the redirect_uri
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Also you can use the following api to get the user details

```
$user_profile =  $facebook->api('/'. $fbuser,'GET');
```

Then add the following below the page. This will check if the user is already logged in it will re-direct to the same page, in other words it will not ask user to login again

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
            {
                FB.init
                ({
                    appId   : 'your fb app id',
                    status  : true, // check login status
                    cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
                    oauth   : true
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function()
                {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };

          (function()
          {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
</script>
```

Comment: yes it works, but only some times, first time it give me the same error.. "Access token", second time.. it works, third time again error.. fourth time.. again it works.. any idea why it's happening ?

Comment: Yes once the user is logged in you need to re-direct user to the same page, can you post the login script that you have added ? Or we need to mark up the JS code below the page I can add that for you if you want ?

Comment: I have modified the answer let me know if still having issue. 'cookie' => true is given in the api.

Comment: did that. not solved yet.. that is for once. when FB.init() redirects.. it comes with fresh access token. but I don't want to refresh page each and every time.. My purpose is to show user friends makes the recent purchase on my website, though I am already using this code to make user login.

Comment: strange try using this $user_profile =  $facebook->api('/'. $fbuser,'GET');

Comment: Yes I have mentioned in the answer as well you may have missed ;)